# No HDMI sound (20.04) until "pulseaudio -k"

Tags: sound, 20.04, pulseaudio, hdmi

Ubuntu 20.04 here (kernel 5.4.0-48)

As stated in the title, after boot I have no sound via HDMI: actually the HDMI interface seems not present at all . [image: see pic here]

I already perused answers to similar questions, and I discovered that a `pulseaudio -k` does the trick: after that the HDMI interface appears and works just fine [image: see here]

Happy?
Actually not, because after a reboot the situation reverts (no sound).
At the moment I resolved doing that `pulseaudio -k` every time, but I'm trying to resolve this for good.

Have you any suggestions or clue about this issue?

Here the syslog [image: syslog]   at startup.
After the refresh of `pulseaudio` I get this: [image]

EDIT: Issue disappered after upgrading to 20.10

Comment: Just to clarify:
pulseaudio -k OR  systemctl --user restart pulseaudio  does the trick.
Bur WHY I 've to to a restart to have pulseaudio to correctly see the HDMI sink ?

Comment: I have the exact same problem after the latest kernel update and no permanent fixes suggested for similar questions work. Do you also lose the sound when the display goes in sleep mode?

If you can find a permanent solution, please update this thread.

Comment: It happens to me, too. And ```pulseaudio -k``` fixes the problem, but I have to do it every login.

Comment: Happening here too: I've started running `pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload` to get it working after logging in.